# How do you inspect a field for graves?

Tags: halacha, how-to, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, agriculture, cemetery-grave

The Gemara (Bab. Nazir 65) discusses some circumstances in which one must inspect a field for graves.

How is this done? 
Do you dig up the earth to a certain depth?
Do you dig a trench? 
Do you dig holes at certain intervals?
The Gemara (65b) says you inspect twenty cubits in one direction. Does it make a difference which direction you inspect?

These are just the issues that I've thought of off the cuff. But my overall question is: What is the process for inspecting a field for graves?

Comment: Since sampling parameters will always(?) fall under * safeiks*, I have a hunch the question may be more easily handling in regards to how to act in an area that has this kind of safeik.  Walking, building, etc.  A secondary question regards what to do if a grave is found in some inopportune location (via archeology, excavation, etc)

Comment: @Zachariah, "The Gemara (Bab. Nazir 65) discusses some circumstances in which one must inspect a field for graves."

Answer (score 1):

You asked: `How is this done? Do you dig up the earth to a certain depth? Do you dig a trench? Do you dig holes at certain intervals?`

It's a Mishna in [Ohalot 16:4](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01243.html#HtmpReportNum0117_L2) which says:

> הַבּוֹדֵק, בּוֹדֵק אַמָּה עַל אַמָּה וּמַנִּיחַ אַמָּה, עַד שֶׁהוּא מַגִּיעַ לְסֶלַע אוֹ לִבְתוּלָה.‏

You check by drilling 1-Amah holes at 1-Amah intervals.

They are reach either bedrock or earth that has clearly never been dug up before. (I don't know how one knows this.)

The Bartenura felaborates, but adds no new information:

> **הַבּוֹדֵק**. הָא דִתְנַן וּבוֹדֵק הֵימֶנּוּ וּלְהַלָּן עֶשְׂרִים אַמָּה, אֵין צָרִיךְ לַחְפֹּר אֶת כֻּלָּן, אֶלָּא חוֹפֵר אַמָּה עַל אַמָּה וּמַנִּיחַ אַמָּה שֶׁאֵינוֹ חוֹפֵר, וְעוֹשֶׂה כֵן עַד שֶׁמַּגִּיעַ לְסוֹף עֶשְׂרִים. וְאוֹתָהּ אַמָּה שֶׁהוּא חוֹפֵר צָרִיךְ לַחְפֹּר עַד שֶׁמַּגִּיעַ לְסֶלַע, אוֹ לִבְתוּלָה, שֶׁהִיא קַרְקַע שֶׁלֹּא נֶחְפְּרָה מֵעוֹלָם: ‏

The Ikar Tosfos YomTov adds that the 1-Amah interval was chosen as it's less than the space between adjacent graves.

> עיקר תוי"ט  {יב} **בּוֹדֵק אַמָּה כוּ'**. לְשׁוֹן הָרַמְבַּ"ם, פָּחוֹת מַה שֶּׁיִּהְיֶה בֵּין קֶבֶר לְקֶבֶר אַמָּה אַחַת כוּ'. וְעַיֵּן תּוֹסְפוֹת יוֹם טוֹב:‏

The next Mishna adds `הָיָה בוֹדֵק, הִגִּיעַ לְנַחַל אוֹ לִשְׁלוּלִית, אוֹ לְדֶרֶךְ הָרַבִּים, מַפְסִיק` . That one only checks until one reaches a river, pond or public thruway.

You also asked: `The Gemara (65b) says you inspect twenty cubits in one direction. Does it make a difference which direction you inspect?`

The Rambam in [הלכות טומאת מת - פרק תשיעי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02029.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L2) words it slightly differently:

> **ו** אֶחָד הַמּוֹצֵא שְׁלֹשָׁה מֵתִים כְּדַרְכָּן בַּתְּחִלָּה אוֹ שֶׁמָּצָא שְׁלֹשָׁה כּוּכִין אוֹ כּוּךְ וּנְקִיעַ וּמְעָרָה הֲרֵי זוֹ שְׁכוּנַת קְבָרוֹת. מָצָא שְׁנַיִם וְאֶחָד הָיָה יָדוּעַ יֵשׁ לָהֶם תְּבוּסָה וְאֵין לָהֶם שְׁכוּנַת קְבָרוֹת שֶׁהַקֶּבֶר הַיָּדוּעַ אֵינוֹ עוֹשֶׂה שְׁכוּנָה. וְלֹא אָמְרוּ אֶלָּא הַמּוֹצֵא שְׁלֹשָׁה בַּתְּחִלָּה הוּא שֶׁצָּרִיךְ בְּדִיקָה. כֵּיצַד בּוֹדֵק הָעֶשְׂרִים אַמָּה שֶׁאָמַרְנוּ. חוֹפֵר עַד שֶׁהוּא מַגִּיעַ לְסֶלַע אוֹ לִבְתוּלָה. וְהִיא הַקַּרְקַע שֶׁנִּרְאֵית שֶׁאֵינָהּ עֲבוּדָה. הֶעְמִיק אֲפִלּוּ מֵאָה אַמָּה וּמָצָא חֶרֶשׂ הֲרֵי זוֹ כְּבַתְּחִלָּה וְצָרִיךְ לְהַעֲמִיק עַד שֶׁיַּגִּיעַ לִבְתוּלָה. הִגִּיעַ לְמַיִם הֲרֵי זוֹ כִּבְתוּלָה:‏
>
> **ז** אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לַחְפֹּר תֶּלֶם אֶחָד מִתְּחִלַּת הָעֶשְׂרִים עַד סוֹפָן אֶלָּא חוֹפֵר אַמָּה עַל אַמָּה וּמַנִּיחַ אַמָּה וְחוֹפֵר אַמָּה עַל אַמָּה וּמַנִּיחַ אַמָּה וְכֵן עַד סוֹפָן שֶׁאֵין בֵּין קֶבֶר לְקֶבֶר פָּחוֹת מֵאַמָּה:‏
>
> **ח** הָיָה בּוֹדֵק וְהִגִּיעַ בְּתוֹךְ הָעֶשְׂרִים לְנָהָר אוֹ לִשְׁלוּלִית אוֹ לְדֶרֶךְ הָרַבִּים יַפְסִיק וְאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לִבְדֹּק שֶׁהֲרֵי נִפְסְקָה שְׁכוּנַת הַקְּבָרוֹת: ‏

The Rambam (ibid:3) says that you check from the last one you find:

> וְצָרִיךְ לִבְדֹּק מִן הָאַחֲרוֹן עֶשְׂרִים אַמָּה שֶׁהֵן כִּשְׁתֵּי מְעָרוֹת וְחָצֵר שֶׁבֵּינֵיהֶן

The Ra'avad argues and says from the first:

> א''א זה שיבוש אלא מן הראשון דבר זה מפרש לה בגמרא דהמוכר פירות איך הוא בא לחשבון זה

I'd imagine in all directions you plan on using. But I can't find anything specific.

Comment: Interesting that the RaAVa"D says that the RaMBa"M flat out contradicts the Gemara. Does anyone correct the text?

Comment: Also, I can't accept this answer until you clarify something. I understood the Gemara to be saying you check in one direction and that this suffices for that field. But you say you assume you have to check in all directions you plan to use. Why? Am I missing something?

Comment: Well done, though I had assumed the "Maniach amah" was referring to the sifting process, not to the "checkering" of the field...

Comment: @SethJ - this has been bothering me for years. What's the point of checking in one direction only? Yet that's what the words say. Still searching.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, any luck?